# Conformal map of polygon with circle segments

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I am looking for a conformal map from a "polygon" to eg the upper half plane, which consists of circle segments instead of lines. So for example, it could be a quadrilateral ABCD, but where AB is a circle segment. The closest I can find is the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping.

Anyone has any tips?

Comment: It seems like the book "Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping" by Driscoll and Trefethen considers circular-arc polygons in section 4.10.

Comment: I see. It is only 3 pages though and considering the other answer is quite involved, I doubt that these three pages will be useful. Do you happen to know the content of that chapter? Cant find the (full) book online..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mapping function is a solution of the Schwarz differential equation
$$\frac{f'''}{f'}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''}{f'}\right)^2=R(z),$$
where $R$ is a rational function with poles at the preimages of the vertices. The poles of $f$ are of second order, and the coefficients at the second order terms are determined by the angles. Schwarz equation can be reduced to a linear differential equation of the form
$y''+Ry/2=0$. In the case of a triangle, this is a hypergeometric equation.
In the case of a quadrilateral, this is a Heun equation.

Literature: Courant, Geometrische Funktionentheorie,
Caratheodory, Funktionentheorie, II, (There is an English translation),
Golubev, Vorlesungen über Differentialgleichungen im Komplexen, (transled from Russian).

The case of a triangle is completely understood (see any book on hypergeometric function)
The case of a quadrilateral is already quite complicated, and there are many
unsolved questions about quadrilaterals and Heun's equation. See for example  arXiv:1409.1529 for some recent results about this, and literature there.

EDIT. More concrete examples can be found here  arXiv:1111.2296 and here  arXiv:1110.2696
and in references to these papers.

Comment: Thank you. The particular problem I have indeed includes a quadrilateral. So if I understand it correctly, when mapping the polygon to a riemann sphere the angles in the polygon becomes the conical singularities?

Also, do you think there is any simplification if one deals with a quadrilateral where only one segment is a circle segment, and the rest straight lines?

Comment: Also, as I wrote to the other commenter, do you know the content of the chapter on "circular arc-polygons" in the book "Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping" by Driscoll? Is it related to the stuff you discuss?

Comment: @user213437: the literature on conformal maps of quadrilaterals is enormous. I am not familiar with that particular book you refer to, but I suppose that it contains some standard material on this.

Comment: @user213437: if you state your problem precisely, perhaps I can give a more specific reference.

Comment: @user213437: yes, the condition all sides but one are straight may give some simplification. It will help if you state your problem more precisely: what are the angles, and what do you want to know about the mapping.

Comment: :The problem is in the following link:
http://s11.postimg.org/50fiu0e03/problem.png
Basically I want to map the shaded region in the left image to the shaded region in the right image, conformally except at A.

Initially I wanted an exact analytic expression for the mapping, but maybe that is too much to ask.

Comment: @user2133437: in this picture two sides (not one) are arcs of circles. The only specific is that two angles are 90 degrees. You may look at my paper  arXiv:1111.2296 where a similar quadrilateral is mapped (in the end of the paper).

Comment: Yes you are right there are two circle segments, I was looking at a mobius transformed version with only one circle segment, but forgot it had one point at infinity. Thanks for your reference, I will have a look but I am a bit skeptical that it will work out since your example is much more specific with basically a=b=0, if I understand you correctly?

Comment: @user2133237: Do I understand correctly that your two polygons have the same angles except one? This may simplify the problem.